# How to make a successful Facebook test API call to grant advanced access permission?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions

I am trying to grant Facebook permission.

On the Facebook 'Permissions and Features' the button 'Request advanced access' is disabled. If you trying to click button the message appears:
"To request advanced access to this permission, you need to make a successful test API call. It may take up to 24 hours after the first API call for this button to become active."

I have make API call but nothing heppend, still Active (0) API calls.

Answer (score 0):

I find solution how to make successful test API call and grant permissions.

If you facing with disabled 'Request advanced access' button and API call is Active (0) here is what you should to do.

1. Go to Admin App page (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/)
2. Find you App, press 3 dots in the right bottom corner and click 'Create Test App' in menu.
3. You will get Test App ID and Test App Secret

Use this credentials to make an API call and in 24 hours you will see  Active (1)